# Issue on Adding a Open Class to Dropdown Menu In Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add `.open` class to `.btn-group` to keep the menu open by doing

```
$('.keep-Open').on('click', function() {
        $('.btn-group').addClass('open');
 });
```

but it is not working!

I do not want to use the

```
.preventDefault(); 
.stopPropagation();
```

since these two stops everyting including chechbox or select options as well so I tought why not to add the `open` class to `.btn-group` on click event? 
can you please let me know why this is not working?

```js
$('.keep-Open').on('click', function() {
        $('.btn-group').addClass('open');
 });
```

```css
body{margin:50px;}
.dropdown-menu{min-width:230px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Single button -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
<div class="list-group">
  <button type="button" class="list-group-item keep-Open">Cras justo odio</button>
  <button type="button" class="list-group-item keep-Open">Dapibus ac facilisis in</button>
  <button type="button" class="list-group-item keep-Open">Morbi leo risus</button>
  <button type="button" class="list-group-item keep-Open">Porta ac consectetur ac</button>
  <button type="button" class="list-group-item keep-Open">Vestibulum at eros</button>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default click handler removes the `open` class, since you don't want to use stop propagation, one solution is to use a timeout(async) call to add the class back

```js
$('.keep-Open').on('click', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.btn-group').addClass('open');
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 50px;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 230px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Single button -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <div class="list-group">
      <button type="button" class="list-group-item keep-Open">Cras justo odio</button>
      <button type="button" class="list-group-item keep-Open">Dapibus ac facilisis in</button>
      <button type="button" class="list-group-item keep-Open">Morbi leo risus</button>
      <button type="button" class="list-group-item keep-Open">Porta ac consectetur ac</button>
      <button type="button" class="list-group-item keep-Open">Vestibulum at eros</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Arun , it is what I was looking for